# non-static vs. static function and variable

Tags: c++

I have one question about static and non-static function and variable.

1) non-static function access static variable.

It's OK!

```
class Bar
{
public:

     static int i;

     void nonStaticFunction() {

         Bar::i = 10;

     }

};

int Bar::i=0;
```

2) non-static function access non-static variable

Definitely OK!

3) static function access static variable&funciton

Definitely OK!

4) static function access non-static function

It's OK

```
class Bar
{
public:
     static void staticFunction( const Bar & bar)
     {
         bar.memberFunction();

     }

     void memberFunction() const
     {

     }

}
```

5) static function access non-static variable

It's OK or not OK? I am puzzled about this!

How about this example

```
class Bar
{
public:
     static void staticFunction( Bar & bar)
     {
         bar.memberFunction();

     }

     void memberFunction()
     {

         i = 0;
     }

     int i;

};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> static function access non-static
>   variable
>
> It's OK or not OK? I am puzzled about
>   this!

When called, a static function isn't bound to an instance of the class. Class instances (objects) are going to be the entities that hold the "non-static" variables. Therefore, from the static function, you won't be able to access them without actually being passed or storing elsewhere a specific instance to operate on.

So yes, the code in your last example is valid, because you are passed in an instance. However, you could not do:

```
static void staticFunction()
{
    // error, this function is static, and is therefore
    // not bound to a specific instance when called
    i = 5;


}
```

Answer (score 9):

Static means this is independent of a particular instance of the class. Static methods don't have access to the `this` pointer. That is the reason you need to call them using the *class name*.

When you call the Static method, you might not even have any instance of the class defined.

non-static means implies an instance, and could be different with different instances.

So, basically, it does not make sense to access non-static members from static methods.

Answer (score 4):

For this, you need to understand what is static.

Static data members exist once for the entire class, as opposed to non-static data members, which exist individually in each instance of a class. They will have a class scope and does not bound to an instance of the class.

To access static member of the class, we use the format as below
::

if you have created 10 objects of a class.
Assume, you were able to access the non-static variable in the static member of the class, When the static function is called, which object's member it needs to change?

Answer (score 2):

It's not ok.  Static functions are accessible without having an instance of a class and thus can't access information that you would need an instance to determine.

For example, you don't need a car to know how many wheels it has, blueprints for a general car would suffice (that could be static information) but you can't tell what color the car is unless you're referring to a specific car (that information needs a specific instance of an object.)